How to solve the problem that after getting independent data from a mutex-protected object, the lock must be kept in Rust?
In actix-web route function, I find that after getting independent data from mutex-protected object, the mutex must be in locking for using these data. If the mutex only locks for getting data, there will be a compile error for using data. Here is code can be compiled directly:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use async_trait::async_trait;
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse, Result as ActixResult};

#[async_trait]
pub trait Reader: Send + Debug { }

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct RemoteReader;

#[async_trait]
impl Reader for RemoteReader { }

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct DataReaders(HashMap<String, Box<dyn Reader>>);

impl DataReaders {
    pub fn get_readers(&self, ids: &str) -> ActixResult<Vec<&dyn Reader>> {
        let mut readers = Vec::new();
        for id in ids.split(',') {
            readers.push(self.0.get(id).unwrap().as_ref());
        }
        Ok(readers)
    }
}

async fn get(data: web::Data<Mutex<DataReaders>>) -> ActixResult<HttpResponse> {
    let mut readers = data.lock().unwrap().get_readers("1,2")?;
    if readers.is_empty() {
        return Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish())
    }
    // Below will call multiple asynchronous functions, so I do not want to
    // hold the lock of DataReaders for a long time.
    readers.clear();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().finish())
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut readers = DataReaders{ 0: Default::default() };
    readers.0.insert("1".to_string(), Box::new(RemoteReader{}));
    readers.0.insert("2".to_string(), Box::new(RemoteReader{}));
    let counter = web::Data::new(Mutex::new(readers));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(counter.clone())
            .route("/", web::get().to(get))
    }).bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?.run().await
}

compile this code and get error:
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:30:23
   |
30 |     let mut readers = data.lock().unwrap().get_readers("1,2")?;
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                       |
   |                       creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
31 |     if readers.is_empty() {
   |        ------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

I only want to use mutex to protected the HashMap because it will be altered in other route functions. I think the Vec<&dyn Reader> object returned from 'get_readers' should not be protected because all items in it is readonly.
So how can I solve this? thanks!

Consider what happens if another route modifies the HashMap in the interim: any &dyn Reader reference that you're holding would be invalidated not only by any modification of the specific map item you're borrowing from, but also by any insertion that causes the map to reallocate (actually any mutation of the HashMap, even of an unrelated item, would invalidate your reference because borrowing occurs at the level of the whole map not individual items).
Therefore unless you move/copy/clone what you're using from the HashMap, the Mutex will need to remain locked.  You might therefore consider holding your objects in refcounted allocations such as Arc<dyn Reader> instead of in Boxes, as these smart pointers can be cheaply cloned so that the lock can then immediately be dropped:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use async_trait::async_trait;
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, HttpResponse, Result as ActixResult};

#[async_trait]
pub trait Reader: Send + Debug { }

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct RemoteReader;

#[async_trait]
impl Reader for RemoteReader { }

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct DataReaders(HashMap<String, Arc<dyn Reader>>);

impl DataReaders {
    pub fn get_readers(&self, ids: &str) -> ActixResult<Vec<Arc<dyn Reader>>> {
        let mut readers = Vec::new();
        for id in ids.split(',') {
            readers.push(self.0.get(id).unwrap().clone());
        }
        Ok(readers)
    }
}

async fn get(data: web::Data<Mutex<DataReaders>>) -> ActixResult<HttpResponse> {
    let mut readers = data.lock().unwrap().get_readers("1,2")?;
    if readers.is_empty() {
        return Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish())
    }
    // Below will call multiple asynchronous functions, so I do not want to
    // hold the lock of DataReaders for a long time.
    readers.clear();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().finish())
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut readers = DataReaders{ 0: Default::default() };
    readers.0.insert("1".to_string(), Arc::new(RemoteReader{}));
    readers.0.insert("2".to_string(), Arc::new(RemoteReader{}));
    let counter = web::Data::new(Mutex::new(readers));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(counter.clone())
            .route("/", web::get().to(get))
    }).bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?.run().await
}


Thank you! I am familiar with C++ , and now I have just started using Rust. I may have unconsciously equated some concepts in Rust with C++. I thought that values of HashMap<String, Box> was pointers to objects on heap, and &dyn Reader was something like a raw pointer. In this way, even if the HashMap changes internally, these pointers will be copied, but the pointed objects will not be affected.So in this HashMap, Box just means the object but not the pointer to an object?

@kyleqian: Both Box<dyn Reader> and &dyn Reader both compile down just to pointers to the trait object on the heap; however the Box (that resides within your HashMap) has ownership of that heap allocation, and your &dyn borrows from it.  The borrow is only valid so long as the compiler can be certain that the Box has not been mutated/dropped, which in turn requires that the HashMap has not been mutated/dropped.

@kyleqian: With unsafe Rust, you can use raw pointers to do away with the borrow checking and therefore avoid the refcounted heap allocation, but responsiblity for upholding the lack of mutation/drop would be entirely yours rather than enforced by the compiler.

@kyleqian Box's addresses will indeed not be changed by resizing the map, however another thread may remove it from the map and this will cause it to be deallocated (this is true in C++ too). If you have an append-only map (so this issue does not exist), you can use a crate that encapsulates this pattern, such as elsa.

@eggyal Thanks for your detailed explain! So this is to avoid the appearance of dangling pointers.

@ChayimFriedman Thank you. You are right, my program does never delete items from the HashMap, but the Rust compiler takes more comprehensive considerations. Even in C++, it's better to use std::shared_ptr here.

@kyleqian: erm, it's not just that the pointers could dangle, but also that assumptions the compiler (and hardware) make about the contents of memory being unchanged might otherwise be violated (eg by another thread mutating the entry in the map that you're using or the contents of the box whilst you're accessing it).

@eggyal Thank you. This Rust code is translated from C++ code, objects in HashMap are added according to requests but never modified or deleted. So there are raw pointers stored in std::unordered_map. In the end, I didn't understand Rust's ownership and borrowing mechanisms well. Thanks.

@ChayimFriedman Thank you for your advices. But elsa::map::FrozenMap still need Mutex to protect insert and get operation?

@kyleqian: you can see that insert works with shared access, so a mutex won't be required.  If you look at the source you can see that under the hood it's implemented with an RwLock.
